# Showing Form1 from Form2

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line-interface

I have been trying to make `Form1` visible from `Form2`. What happens in my program is that you press a button in `form1` to hide `form1`, then `Form2` will pop up... But when a timer runs out on `Form2`, It is supposed to hide itself and `Form1` is supposed to pop back up.
But When I try and run I get this:

```
1>c:\users\devon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\retaliation\retaliation\Form2.h(122): error C2039: 'Form1' : is not a member of 'Retaliation::Form2'
```

(Ps. Retaliation is the name of the program).

Here is my code (Which has `#include "Form1.h"` at the top)

```
   #pragma once
   #include "stdAfx.h"
   #include "Form1.h"

   namespace Retaliation {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace std;


/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form2
/// </summary>
public ref class Form2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    int MoviePlay;

public: 
    int TickL;
    Form2(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form2()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer^  MoviePlayer1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Timer^  timer1;
private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;
protected: 

protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>


   #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources =  (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form2::typeid));
        this->MoviePlayer1 = (gcnew AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer());
        this->timer1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer(this- >components));
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >   (this->MoviePlayer1))->BeginInit();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // MoviePlayer1
        // 
        this->MoviePlayer1->Enabled = true;
        this->MoviePlayer1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, -1);
        this->MoviePlayer1->Name = L"MoviePlayer1";
        this->MoviePlayer1->OcxState =  (cli::safe_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AxHost::State^  >(resources- >GetObject(L"MoviePlayer1.OcxState")));
        this->MoviePlayer1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(860, 547);
        this->MoviePlayer1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->MoviePlayer1->Enter += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form2::axWindowsMediaPlayer1_Enter);
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this->timer1->Interval = 1000;
        this->timer1->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form2::timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // Form2
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(859, 495);
        this->Controls->Add(this->MoviePlayer1);
        this->Name = L"Form2";
        this->Text = L"Form2";
        this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form2::Form2_Load);
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->MoviePlayer1))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
   #pragma endregion
private: System::Void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_Enter(System::Object^  sender,     System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void Form2_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             String^ Movie = File::ReadAllText("Movie.txt");
             if (Movie == "1")
             {

             MoviePlayer1 -> Ctlcontrols -> play();
             }

         }
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             TickL += 1;
             if (Movie == "1")
             {
             if (TickL == 47)
             {
                 this -> timer1 -> Stop();
                 TickL = 0;
                 this -> Hide();
                 this -> Form1 -> Show();

             }
             }
         }
};
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to pass a reference to `Form1` at the time it creates and shows `Form2`. Then, when `Form2` closes, it can use that reference to show `Form1` again.

So change your `Form2` to have a `private` member variable to reference `Form1` and set this in the constructor

```
public ref class Form2 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
private:
    Form1 ^m_pMainForm;

public: 
    Form2(Form1 ^pMainForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // save reference to main form
        m_pMainForm = pMainForm;
    }
    // ... etc.
```

Then change the code in `Form1` that creates `Form2` to pass a reference to itself

```
public SomeMethodInForm1()
{
    // create and show Form2
    Form2 ^pFormTwo = gcnew Form2(this);  // pass a reference to Form1
    pFormTwo->Show();
}
```

Finally, in `Form2`, you can use the saved reference to redisplay `Form1`

```
public SomeMethodInForm2()
{
    // redisplay Form1
    m_pMainForm->Show();

    // ... close Form2 or whatever you want to do
}
```

Depending on the order of your class declarations, you may need to add a forward declaration for one of the forms, or maybe split the code appropriately between header and definition, but that's a small detail. Just post another question if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

While calling form2 from form1 hide form1 and then call form2. After calling form2 unhide form1.

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
this->Visible = false;
Form2^ f2 = gcnew Form2;
f2->ShowDialog();
```

this->Visible = true;

```
     }
```

};